# How to create a game launcher with no borders?

Tags: c#

What is a good way to create a game launcher with no borders and has a transparent background like that of Guild Wars 2?

Guild Wars 2 example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdlY4.jpg

Even though it doesn't look like it has a background, it is kinda clear in this next image.
https://dviw3bl0enbyw.cloudfront.net/uploads/forum_attachment/file/1678/Guild_Wars_2_Crash_image.jpg

Which programming language should I use to be able to do that? Is this possible in C#? If so, which tools in C# should I use?

Comment: Look in to WPF/XAML, yes C# will work [and easily].

Comment: To answer to your last question, it's possible with C# by using `System.Windows.SplashScreen`

Comment: You can go with `electron` - `node JS ` also

Comment: Thanks for all your answers everyone! Never heard of these tools before, but I will look into them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be done with a Splashscreen. A splashscreen provides a startup screen for a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) application. You can use it to show an image in a startup window, or splash screen, when a WPF application starts.

The SplashScreen class can display any image format that is supported by the Windows Imaging Component (WIC). For example, you can use the BMP, GIF, JPEG, PNG, or TIFF format. If the image is a PNG file and it includes an alpha channel, the image is rendered using the transparency defined in the alpha channel.

```
SplashScreen splashScreen = new SplashScreen("SplashScreenImage.bmp");
splashScreen.Show(true);
```

From msdn:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.splashscreen(v=vs.110).aspx